# Conversion between 2 different coordinate systems

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I am using the math from this artice: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635757(v=vs.85).aspx to create a generic conversions matrix I can use to convert between 2 coordinate systems.

If I apply it to the examples the math works perfectly, but if I try to use it between 2 coordinate systems defined by these points

$$(x1, y1) = (1, 1)$$
$$(x'1, y'1) = (1, 1)$$
$$(x2, y2) = (2, 2)$$
$$(x'2, y'2) = (2, 2)$$

Basically, this is the same coordinate system so I would expect a transformation on a point to result in the same point.

Using the math from the article I get this

$$\mathbf{M} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    2 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
    -2 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$\mathbf{u} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    2 \\
    2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

And the result is that

$$a=0$$$$b=1$$$$c=0$$$$d=0$$

examplified here as well: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inv%7B%7B1,1,1,+0%7D,%7B-1,1,0,1%7D,+%7B2,+2,+1,+0%7D,+%7B-2,+2,+0,+1%7D%7D+.+%7B%7B1%7D,+%7B1%7D,+%7B2%7D,+%7B2%7D+%7D

So when I use these numbers to convert (2, 1) I would like to get (2, 1) but I get (1, 2)

$$x = ax + by + c = 0*2 + 1*1 + 0 = 1$$
$$y = bx - ay + d = 1*2 + 0*1 + 0 = 2$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Answer (score 1):

What you have gotten is a transformation which reflects your coordinate system across the $y=x$ line; in other words, it switches the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis. So $(1,1)$ is still $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ is still $(2,2)$, but $(2,1)$ becomes $(1,2)$, as you noted.

For whatever reason, the math in that article doesn't allow a transformation which keeps the coordinate system the same. Getting $x' = x$ which require $a = 1$, but getting $y' = y$ would require $a = -1$.

Comment: Is there a way I can create a matrix that will work with the coordinate system that is the same (or very similar)?